# TfvcTemplate.12.xaml missing in Source Control

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm using the the hosted TFS from Microsoft at VisualStudio.com via VS2012

When I create a new Build Definition I'm presented with the following templates choose from:

[image]

If I select TfVcTemplate.12.xaml

my build comes up with the following warnings:

[image]

So I'm thinking that I probably need to set some defaults in the template and everything should be fine, however when I go to Build Process Templates in the root of TFS Project I see can't see the template. No amount of get latest/shutdown/restart etc will bring it up.

[image]

Comment: Found your post since I'm getting the same 5 as failing, I did read here: http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/whats-new-in-tfs-2013-build/ that they aren't located in source control anymore, so that appears to be normal. Now to figure out why they are failing :(

Comment: @John Excellent find! I'd prefer not customise and rather use Post/Pre hook instead

Answer (score 6):

The *12.xaml templates only work properly with VS2013.  (VS2013 is Visual Studio version 12.0). They reference some assemblies that only VS2013 knows about.

Since you're opening the templates in VS2012, this is why you're seeing the errors.

For reference the *11.xaml templates work with VS2012 (since it's Visual Studio version 11.0) and also with VS2013.

Comment: Yeah I sort of gathered that. I was hoping there was a way. But thank you for clarifying. I'll have to upgrade!

Comment: Wow thanks... so simple. I have both 2013 and 2012 and didn't even realize I was using 2012 when I first tried after upgrading to TFS 2013.